# How to simply index the coordinates of a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw this figure :
[image]

using the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major]

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the optimal solution. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: I did edit my original post. I hope this will work. I'm a beginner so don't judge me from jumpstart :D

Comment: @jerhaouiothmane, `\usepackage` should be in preamble not in document body. By the way, it is not necessary to use `tikz`.

Comment: "optimal" is a bit subjective.  Are you going to have anything else in that plot, or just what you've shown us?

Comment: @Sigur yes you're right I have it in the right place in my code sorry

Comment: @Teepeemm No all I want is that plot. I'm sure there another option other that plot that would be way more optimal to draw this. I just don't know it.

Comment: @jerhaouiothmane, it is not difficult. Basically, a lot of `\draw (x,y) -- (z,w);` commands would do. Of course, you can simplify making use of loops, `\foreach` and others.

Comment: @jerhaouiothmane Could you change the title of the question such as "How to simply index the coordinates of a grid" so that the title can be used by search engines when indexing them?

Comment: I just modified the title

Answer (score 2):

I am very far from claiming that this is the "optimal" solution, but it is certainly possible to add a few ingredients to your code to make the result come very close to the desired screen shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,
        axis equal image,
        grid=major,grid style={densely dotted,help lines},
        axis x line=bottom,
        xmin=-0.5,xmax=9.5,xtick={0,1,...,9},xticklabel=$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber\tick}$,
        axis y line=box,
        ymin=0,ymax=4.2,ytick={0,1,...,4},yticklabel=$t^{\pgfmathprintnumber\tick}$,
        axis line style={draw,thick,-},
        ]
        \path (0,0) coordinate (O) (1,1) coordinate (X) (9,0) coordinate (9);
    \end{axis}
    \draw[dashed,<->] ([yshift=-1cm]current axis.south-|O) -- 
        node[below] {$h$} ([yshift=-1cm]current axis.south-|X);
    \draw[dashed,<->] ([xshift=-1cm]current axis.west|-O) -- 
        node[left] {$k$} ([xshift=-1cm]current axis.west|-X);
    \draw[->] (9) -- ++ (1,0);  
    \path (current axis.south west) node[below]{$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer